# Search array of java custom objects

Tags: java

I have an array of custom objects CustomClass[] customArr where CustomClass is like

```
Class CustomClass{

private String key;
private String value;

//getter & setters

}
```

Now I want to search this array by a particular value.What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 5):

Implement [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Make sure you comply with the contract of the method.

Also, if you search often and the array is large you probably want to consider a better data structure for this, e.g. one of the implementations of `Set` if you're interested in the presence of particular instances within the data structure or one of the implementations of `Map` if you want to search by a key. See [`java.util`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) for details.

Note that some of the data structures in `java.util` may require you to provide your own version of [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) (e.g. [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)) and some may require you to implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface or provide a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (e.g. [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)).

If you provide your own version of `hashCode()` make sure it is consistent with your `equals()` (see the javadoc for `equals()`).

If you really must use an array, then consider one of the versions of [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29). Note that you can only use it on sorted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Comparable. Then you can use `java.util.Arrays` to search and sort your array.

```
Class CustomClass implements Comparable {

private String key;
private String value;

//getter & setters 

public int compareTo(Object other){
     if( other instanceOf CustomClass )
     {
         CustomClass otherCustomClass = (CustomClass) other;
         int val = this.key.compareTo( otherCustomClass.key  );
         if( key != 0 ) return key;
         return this.value.compareTo( otherCustomClass.value );
     }
     return -1;
}

}
```